# Angular 6 - Issue displaying data with *ngFor (data not showing)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have some data that looks like this:

[image]

On my `app.component.html` I have this:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let data of myData">{{data.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

When I run this it show the lists but without any values so I just get lots of dots from the `<li>`

On my `app.component.ts` I have:

```
myData;
```

and then:

```
this.myData = obj; // Obj contains the data
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show what `console.log(myData)` prints?

Comment: Console.log will show the data I provided in the question

Comment: print data of myData in html page using interpolation see what data object is Like <li *ngFor="let data of myData">{{data}}</li>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<ul *ngFor="let data of myData">
  <li>{{data.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

You're creating multiple `<ul>` elements, while you probably want to have multiple `<li> (list item)` elements:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let data of myData">{{data.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the data from the console so you can see how it looks better

Comment: Try with `<li *ngFor="let data of myData.listResponse.instance">{{data.@attributes.id}}</li>`

Comment: It doesn't like the @ character in @attributes

Comment: When I change the app.component.ts code to: this.myData = obj.listResponse.instance; there are no errors but the empty <li>'s are back

Comment: It's still not enough. Can you `console.log(obj.listResponse.instance[0])`?

Comment: That returns: @attributes: { id: "1" }

Comment: Post a screenshot like in original post please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171013/discussion-between-ritaj-and-paul-b).

Answer (score 4):

Because I guess you created array object something like this

```
 myData = [
    {
      '@attributes:': 'id:1'
    },
    {
      '@attributes:': 'id:2'
    }
  ];
```

That is wrong and has to be like this.First Check your array or array Object.

```
 myData = [
    {
      attribute: 'abc',
      id: 1
    },
    {
      attribute: 'bcs',
      id: 2
    }
  ];
```

and in Html file

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let data of myData">{{data.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the data from the console so you can see how it looks better

Answer (score 2):

Give Data to myData variable like this==>

```
    this.myService.myFunction().subscribe(res=>
    this.myData = res['listResponse']['@attributes']['instance']
     )}
```